# Windows 10 'cannot import name 'getuid' from 'os'

Tags: bash, error-handling, git-bash

When I try to open the py with python3 in bash I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'getuid' from 'os'` im trying to open the agreement to HiddenEye but I dont see why im getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like os.getuid() is a Unix only function. You'll either need to edit the code to use cross-platform function, or run it on a Unix OS.

Source: https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/issues/415